# What are the recommended learning material for SSIS?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

Okay, you don't need to be a guru, but if you happen to have a good working knowledge on SSIS and you used some tutorials around the web to get you there, then please share them. I have been trying to find some solid stuff (screencasts maybe), but I am having a hard time.

Any solid links would be appreciated and I will add them to this question in an aggregated format at the end. Thank you.

So far we have:

http://blogs.conchango.com/jamiethomson

http://sqlis.com

Answer (score 8):

http://blogs.conchango.com/jamiethomson/ A very, very good place to start,

Comment: I second this link.. very invaluable.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend [en excellent series of articles by Marcin Policht](http://www.databasejournal.com/article.php/1503191)

There are about 50 articles at the moment and each focuses on different aspect of the SSIS, they are pretty detailed and I found them to be an excellent source of information on the subject of SSIS

Answer (score 2):

Another great resource besides Cochango (great blog btw!) is http://www.sqlis.com/

I also found these two books to be very helpful:

[Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Integration Services](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672327813)

[Expert SQL Server 2005 Integration Services](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470134119)

I read them in the order that they are listed above.

Comment: Ah of course, Trash Adapter FTW

Comment: Trash Adapter is pretty neat!

Comment: Have you ever called a SSIS package from managed code Hector? Do you have a link to that task?

Comment: Ryan: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136090.aspx

Answer (score 2):

These links are mainly components, but they have good information resources also.

http://www.sqlbi.com/ - Some great SSIS components for data warehousing BI
http://www.konesans.com/products.aspx - Some more useful components

Answer (score 1):

The current Jamie Thomson blog is located here, where he continues to write about ETL stuff:

http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jamie_thomson/

Answer (score 0):

SSIS tutorials for the beginner: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms169917.aspx

BI Monkey has some good examples: http://www.bimonkey.com/

SSIS team blog: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattm/