# Linq To Sql and identity_insert

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

I am trying to do record inserts on a table where the Primary Key is an `Identity` field.

I have tried calling
`mycontext.ExecuteCommand("SET identity_insert myTable ON")`
but this doesn't do any good.

I get an error saying `IDENTITY_INSERT` is `OFF` when I submit changes.

How can I turn it `ON` from the C# code before I submit changes?

### EDIT

I have read that this is because ExecuteCommand's code gets executed in a different session.

### EDIT 2

Is there any way I can execute some DDL to remove the Identity Specification from my C# code, do the inserts, and then turn Identity Specification back on?

Comment: Why do you want to turn the identity  insert on, this is a very dangerous thing to do (it does nto affect just your process) and should not be done to production data unless the database is in maintenance mode or you are sure (and that means no one else has permissions to do so) no other users can enter data into the table at the same time you are doing your task.

Comment: It's not a production database. I am doing a transfer to a development database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do all the steps in a single T-SQL code block - which is going to be really hard if not impossible if you want to turn it on, then execute your LINQ-to-SQL query, and then turn it back off :(

The only real solution I see is to package up the entire SQL into a SQL statement and execute that:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT MyTable ON

(do your update here)

SET IDENTITY_INSERT MyTable OFF
```

and execute that as a single code block using `.ExecuteContext()`

Marc

PS: for your EDIT#2 : no, unfortunately, there's no (easy) way to remove the identity from a column, and turn it back on. Basicall you'd have to create a new column without the IDENTITY, copy the values over, drop the IDENTITY column and then do the same backwards when you're done - sorry! :-(

PS #2: this really begs the question: what on earth to do need to do an "identity insert" for? On a regular basis, from an app? Granted - you might run into this need once in a while, but I'd always do this separately, in SQL Mgmt Studio - certainly not in my app..... (just curious what your use case / motivation is).

Comment: @PS#2 read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368494/transfer-transform-data-from-sql-server-2008-db-to-another

I was going to go ahead and try to code the work, but I may end up learning SSIS. Any advice?

Comment: I never said it was for a regular basis. I am transfering/transforming data and I don't know a damn thing about SSIS.

Comment: OK, in that case, why don't you just do it with straight SQL then? Yes - Linq would be nice - but if it's a one-off - just drop to plain SQL and avoid all the problems and limitations :-)

Comment: Either use straight SQL in your app, or go with SSIS - that's really SSIS's whole reason to be - extract-transform-load data from one source to another :-)

Answer (score 19):

Another option is to wrap all your Linq2Sql calls in a TransactionScope().  This should force them all to run in the same connection.

```
using System.Transactions; // Be sure to add a reference to System.Transactions.dll to your project.

       // ... in a method somewhere ...
       using (System.Transaction.TransactionScope trans = new TransactionScope())
       {
          using(YourDataContext context = new YourDataContext())
          {
             context.ExecuteCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT MyTable ON");

             context.ExecuteCommand("yourInsertCommand");

             context.ExecuteCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT MyTable OFF");
          }
          trans.Complete();
       }
       // ...
```

Although, if you are trying to do something like:

```
context.ExecuteCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT MyTable ON");
context.MyTable.InsertOnSubmit(myTableObject)
context.SubmitChanges()
context.ExecuteCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT MyTable OFF");
```

you will probably run into other issues, especially if the identity column has the IsDbGenerated attribute set to true.  The SQL command generated by Linq2Sql will not know to include the identity column and value.

Comment: This is the freaking solution! So it is possible!

Answer (score 3):

It should be enough to open the connection manually before executing commands. This makes the commands run in the same session:

```
context.Connection.Open();
context.ExecuteCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT MyTable ON");
// make changes
// ...
context.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: I know it says to avoid +1 and "thanks", but I simply can't help it. I was stuck on this for hours. I was using a context and Linq to SQL and submitting changes and it always said that my IDENTITY_INSERT was off. All I had to do was open the connection. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

What I did is something like this(Nbuider is used to create entities). I create all rows normally except the identity insert row; which is done in the end. This is test data creation hence transaction was not needed.

```
using (var entitiesEfContext = new ContextABC())
{

    var platforms = Builder<Platform>
                                .CreateListOfSize(4)
                                .TheFirst(1)
                                .With(x => x.Description = "Desc1")
                                .With(x => x.IsDeleted = false)
                                .TheNext(1)
                                .With(x => x.Description = "Desc2")
                                .With(x => x.IsDeleted = false)
                                .TheNext(1)
                                .With(x => x.Description = "Desc3")
                                .With(x => x.IsDeleted = false)
                                .TheNext(1)
                                .With(x => x.Description = "Desc4")
                                .With(x => x.IsDeleted = false)
                                .Build();
                foreach (var platform in platforms)
                {
                    entitiesEfContext.Platform.AddObject(platform);
                }
                entitiesEfContext.SaveChanges();

              // the identity insert row (o as id in my case)

               entitiesEfContext.ExecuteStoreCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT Platform ON; INSERT INTO [Platform](Platformid,[Description],[IsDeleted],[Created],[Updated]) VALUES (0,'Desc0' ,0 ,getutcdate(),getutcdate());SET IDENTITY_INSERT Platform Off");


              }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message. And I resolve it by changing the properties of the Primary key in the table.

```
MyTable.MyId int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
```

The property settings MyId (in the **dbml**)

- Auto Generated Value: **True**;
- Auto-Sync: **OnInsert**;
- Primary Key: **True**;
- Server Data Type: **int NOT NULL IDENTITY**;
- Type: **int**;

Comment: these are the default settings... what did you actually change?

Answer (score 0):

just simple `reseed identity key` (with custom id) every time you add new record, eg:

```
    using (var desDb = new DesDbContext())
    {
        // del-table-all --------------------------------------------------------
        desDb.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("DELETE FROM [Products]");

        foreach (var desItem in desList) //desList is List of Product
        {
            // reseed identity key
            desDb.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("DBCC CHECKIDENT('Products', RESEED," 
                + (desItem.ProductID - 1) + ");");

            // and record
            desDb.Products.Add(desItem);                        

            // save-db                    
            desDb.SaveChanges();

        }
    }
```