# Potential conflict between transferring data and '.ValueGeneratedOnAdd()'

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I apologize if this is duplicative; I could find nothing directly pertaining.

The difficulty involves EF Core (v 3.1.8, if it matters), but is not specific or restricted thereto. I am doing code first, creating a number of entities, but the key point is that I am getting my initial data set from an app that I am trying to replace. My new app has a number of structural differences in every corresponding entity, but the data in the old app is still critical, so I will be transferring it to my new database. (Old db is hosted by MS SQL 2008; new db is hosted by MS SQL 2019, if it matters).

Most of the key fields are GUIDs, and the problem is that in EF Core, at the point in the future when I want to use the new app to do more data entry, I will also want the database to choose the GUID. In EF Core Fluent API parlance, that would be, for example:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity("ReplaceOldApp.Models.Address", b =>
    {
        b.Property<Guid>("AddressID")
           .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
           .HasColumnType("uniqueidentifier");
    }
```

However, if I inform EF Core that I want the database to create the key, then it will create the tables such that when I try to transfer the data from the old database (whether using EF or some other means), the new database will ignore the old GUID and create a new, unrelated one. (Or at least, that's what I think will happen. I'm not ready to try it yet.) If that happens, then all of the data from, say, the old Person entity (such as the above-implied Address entity), will no longer be related between their corresponding entities in the new database, because all records will have shiny new GUIDs. I will have all the information, and no way to actually use it.

Obviously I can tell EF Core to inform the database that it will not be creating the GUIDs, and I can then read, unmunge and transfer the data from the old database to the new without fear of data loss (God willing). But then going forward, for any new data entry, the GUIDs will not be automatically genned. I can of course then mod my `IEntityTypeConfiguration` Fluent API classes for the various entities and do a second migration, re-genning the affected tables, but I'm worried that EF Core will decide that it needs to `DROP` the tables to accommodate such a change. (Again, I do not know for sure because I have not tried it: sorry.)

So my question is: How would you approach such a situation? Should I ignore EF and do something clever with MS SQL Studio? Should I do two migrations with a transfer in-between? Should I tell the database, even though it has been told to gen the keys, somehow to accept the old keys without changing things, perhaps via `LINQ`?

============== Edit:

I'm sure SSIS would work to transfer the data from old to new databases, but the learning curve appears daunting, and I am only trying to solve one problem, not gain a new career. Powershell ditto, although it may be a bit more of a hacker's tool, and as such knowledge of it might assist tweaking or help to solve a diverse set of one-time SQL Server headaches. However, again, as would you, I prefer to use what I know, or failing that, learn or learn more about a tool which promises to serve me consistently into the future.

With the very welcome new (to me) information about `IDENTITY_INSERT`, and information gained from *[Linq To Sql and identity_insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368987/linq-to-sql-and-identity-insert)*, I believe I should *not* use LINQ to SQL because it may assume that `IDENTITY_INSERT` is `OFF` and simply filter out the crucial GUID, failing therefore to provide it to the target server. Rather, it seems I can use C# to produce a series of generated SQL statements, and then run each one on the target server inside a `TransactionScope()`. Because each such insert will thereby run 'in the same connection', the state of `IDENTITY_INSERT` will be preserved for that entire insert transaction, and (creek don't rise) it should work.

Again, I appreciate your answer, [Randy in Marin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13024949/randy-in-marin). It has, it seems, led me to an approach that will work within the potential constraints of my context (EF Core), while allowing me to preserve the crucial existing `IDENTITY` information. Peace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not being an EF programmer, I don't know if there is an option for identity insert that you can enable for a migration.  You might search the term to see if it comes up.

Our team support database migrations.  We can do it a number of ways.  I would not even consider EF because it's not designed for data migrations - or for database design.  (And because we tend to use what we know.)

This is not the way I would do it, but it might be better than SSIS if you have not used SSIS.  If the tables are in the same database or in databases on the same server, you can use T-SQL to load each table one at a time.  Even if not on the same server, a linked server would allow a distributed transaction.  (I avoid linked servers like the plague, but for a one time thing like a migration I would tolerate it.  I would rather restore a copy of the source database to the destination server to use as a source.  Distributed transactions gone wrong have forced me to reboot critical servers.)

Each table can have a 4 part name.  If the server part (e.g., using a linked server name) is not present, the local instance is used.  If the database part is not present, the current database is used.  This is the format I assume for the "src_table" and "dst_table".

[myserver\myinstance].[mydatabase].[myschema].[mytable]

Each table is loaded with T-SQL as follows:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE dst_table
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dst_table ON  
INSERT dst_table (...) SELECT ... FROM src_table 
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dst_table OFF -- must be turned off - only 1 table can have this ON
```

If there are foreign keys, some tables (e.g., def tables) would need to be loaded first.

If the table does not have an IDENTITY column (EF code creates all values), you don't use the IDENTITY_INSERT stuff.  It will fail if you use it and there is not an identity column.  It will fail if you don't use it and try to insert into an identity column.

If there is a lot of data in a table, the transaction might be too big or slow.  Inserting in batches might be called for.

If it was something to run on a schedule, I would likely create a SSIS package to do the load.

If I wanted to try something new, I would use powershell and the DBATools module cmdlets to see if extracting to csv and importing the csv would be efficient.  The import cmdlet has a column mapping parameter, among many others.  PowerShell could be used to do transformation, but I think this crosses over into SSIS territory.

I have dealt with migrations where the GUIDs and IDs no longer related after the move.  Using queries joining the new data to the old data, we were able to fix the related values. It's likely more work to fix it after than to plan for it to be correct from the start.

Comment: Appreciated! The Powershell option is interesting. It would give another per-table backup and allow manipulation of the CSV file content before import.

But the most interesting thing you told me is about `IDENTITY_INSERT`, since that may provide a doorway to using either SQL or C# to do the transfer. If I understand correctly, the command is named from the point of view of the database *user*, so that when it is `OFF`, the database gens the GUID, and when it is `ON`, the user 'inserts' the GUID. I assume it needs to be set for each insert. I think it might solve my problem.

Comment: Ran out of chars... I will revisit to mark the question 'answered' after some tests.