# Fastest method to fill a database table with 10 Million rows

Tags: database, performance, language-agnostic

What is the fastest method to fill a database table with 10 Million rows? I'm asking about the technique but also about any specific database engine that would allow for a way to do this as fast as possible. I"m not requiring this data to be indexed during this initial data-table population.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the nature of the data that you're attempting to fill the database with? If it's junk data, just run functions on the server to insert dummy rows. If it's data trapped in a file, consider vendor specific bulk import/bcp tools.

Comment: What I have for now: Firebird database, want to fill it up with data for testing purposes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using SQL to load a lot of data into a database will usually result in poor performance. In order to do things quickly, you need to go around the SQL engine. Most databases (including Firebird I think) have the ability to backup all the data into a text (or maybe XML) file and to restore the entire database from such a dump file. Since the restoration process doesn't need to be transaction aware and the data isn't represented as SQL, it is usually very quick.

I would write a script that generates a dump file by hand, and then use the database's restore utility to load the data.

After a bit of searching I found [FBExport](http://fbexport.sourceforge.net/), that seems to be able to do exactly that - you'll just need to generate a CSV file and then use the FBExport tool to import that data into your database.

Answer (score 2):

The ***fastest*** method is probably running an INSERT sql statement with a SELECT FROM. I've generated test data to populate tables from other databases and even the same database a number of times. But it all depends on the nature and availability of your own data. In my case i had enough rows of collected data where a few select/insert routines with random row selection applied half-cleverly against real data yielded decent test data quickly. In some cases where table data was uniquely identifying i used intermediate tables and frequency distribution sorting to eliminate things like uncommon names (eliminated instances where a count with group by was less than or equal to 2)

Also, [Red Gate](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Data_Generator) actually provides a utility to do just what you're asking. It's not free and i think it's Sql Server-specific but their tools are top notch. Well worth the cost. There's also a free trial period.

If you don't want to pay or their utility you could conceivably build your own pretty quickly. What they do is not magic by any means. A decent developer should be able to knock out a similarly-featured though alpha/hardcoded version of the app in a day or two...

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853576/upload-a-massive-csv-file-to-sql-server-database). It looks at uploading a massive CSV file to a SQL server (2005) database. For SQL Server, it appears that a SSIS DTS package is the fastest way to bulk import data into a database.

Answer (score 1):

It entirely depends on your DB.  For instance, Oracle has something called direct path load (http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96652/ch09.htm), which effectively disables indexing, and if I understand correctly, builds the binary structures that will be written to disk on the -client- side rather than sending SQL over.

Combined with partitioning and rebuilding indexes per partition, we were able to load a 1 billion row (I kid you not) database in a relatively short order.  10 million rows is nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Use MySQL or MS SQL and embedded functions to generate records inside the database engine. Or generate a text file (in cvs like format) and then use Bulk copy functionality.