# How can I get a percentage of LINQ to SQL submitchanges?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I wonder if anyone else has asked a similar question.

Basically, I have a huge tree I'm building up in RAM using LINQ objects, and then I dump it all in one go using `DataContext.SubmitChanges()`.

It works, but I can't find how to give the user a sort of visual indication of how far has the query progressed so far. If I could ultimately implement a sort of progress bar, that would be great, even if there is a minimal loss in performance.

Note that I have quite a large amount of rows to put into the DB, over 750,000 rows.
I haven't timed it exactly, but it does take a long while to put them in.

**Edit:** I thought I'd better give some indication of what I'm doing.

Basically, I'm building a suffix tree from the Lord of the Rings. Thus, there are a lot of Nodes, and certain Nodes have positions associated to them (Nodes that happen to be at the end of a suffix). I am building the Linq objects along these lines.

```
suffixTreeDB.NodeObjs.InsertOnSubmit(new NodeObj()
{
    NodeID = 0,
    ParentID = 0,
    Path = "$"
});
```

After the suffix tree has been fully generated in RAM (which only takes a few seconds), I then call `suffixTreeDB.submitChanges();`

What I'm wondering is if there is any faster way of doing this. Thanks!

**Edit 2:** I've did a stopwatch, and apparently it takes precisely 6 minutes for the DB to be written.

Comment: It's a datastructure: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you divide the calls you are doing, as they are sent in separate calls to the db   anyway. This will also reduce the size of the transaction (which linq does when calling submitchanges).

If you divide them in 10 blocks of 75.000, you can provide a rough estimate on a 1/10 scale.

**Update 1:** After re-reading your post and your new comments, I think you should take a look at SqlBulkCopy instead. If you need to improve the time of the operation, that's the way to go. Check this related question/answer: [What's the fastest way to bulk insert a lot of data in SQL Server (C# client)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24200/whats-the-fastest-way-to-bulk-insert-a-lot-of-data-in-sql-server-c-client/24224#24224)

Comment: Could you indicate how I can do this after I've instantiated all the Linq objects please? Or should I stop after every 100,000 Linq object instantiations and flush to DB or something?

Comment: @Jean I mean the flush to DB approach

Comment: I've finally redone this with SqlBulkCopy. Now it's much faster, about 52 seconds, I consider this quite good, considering I am on a laptop with a crappy HDD.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get percentage progress for ctx.submitchanges() by using ctx.Log and ActionTextWriter

```
ctx.Log = new ActionTextWriter(s => {
if (s.StartsWith("INSERT INTO"))
    insertsCount++;
    ReportProgress(insertsCount);
});
```

more details are available at my blog post
http://epandzo.wordpress.com/2011/01/02/linq-to-sql-ctx-submitchanges-progress/

and stackoverflow question
[LINQ to SQL SubmitChangess() progress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4563828/linq-to-sql-submitchangess-progress)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't ideal, but you could create another thread that periodically queries the table you're populating to count the number of records that have been inserted.  I'm not sure how/if this will work if you are running in a transaction though, since there could be locking/etc.

Comment: I don't think I can do it, as I've actually tried executing queries while submitChanges was being executed, but nothing was shown.

Comment: If you don't set the transaction property, and there is no scoped transaction, Linq will automatically create a transaction that wraps the SubmitChanges execution. This ensures that all the changes are made, or none are made. It also means you won't see anything until Commit is called at the end.

Answer (score 0):

What I really think I need is a form of Bulk-Insert, however it appears that Linq doesn't support it.