# SqlBulkCopy takes long time to insert datatable records into SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server

We are trying to insert 20000 or more records using `SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer` method, but it is taking 140 sec to insert into the table.

Is there any way we can improve the time using `SqlBulkCopy` as this is widely used for bulk insertion?

Calling code:

```
using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(dConn)) 
{
    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("SamplingFileId", "SamplingFileId");
    /*... 74 more columns ...*/
    bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 500; //Assign Destination Table Name
    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "cvr_ReviewSamplingLoans";
    bulkCopy.BatchSize = 5000; 
    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dtLoansToUpload);
}
```

Sql Table Definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ReviewSamplingLoans](
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1000,1) NOT NULL,
[SamplingFileId] [int] NOT NULL,
[ReviewId] [int] NOT NULL,
[LoanType] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
[LoanNumber] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[BorrowerName] [nvarchar](150) NOT NULL,
[OriginalUPB] [money] NOT NULL,
[CurrentUPB] [money] NOT NULL,
[OriginalMonthlyPayment] [money] NULL,
[CurrentMonthlyP&I] [money] NULL,
[PaymentFrequency] [nvarchar](2) NULL,
[OriginalNoteRate] [float] NULL,
[CurrentInterestRate] [float] NULL,
[OriginationDate] [date] NULL,
[MaturityDate] [date] NULL,
[FirstPaymentDate] [date] NULL,
[InterestPaidThruDate] [date] NULL,
[NextPaymentDate] [date] NULL,
[DelinquencyStatus] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
[LatePaymentCount] [int] NULL,
[StatedTerm] [int] NULL,
[OriginalAmortizationTerm] [int] NULL,
[NoteType] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
[RateType] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
[LoanProductType] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
[BalloonDueDate] [date] NULL,
[BalloonPaymentAmount] [money] NULL,
[PropertyCity] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[PropertyState] [nchar](2) NULL,
[PropertyZipcode] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
[PropertyType] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
[PropertyTypeDescription] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[LienPosition] [tinyint] NULL,
[OriginalLTV] [float] NULL,
[CurrentLTV] [float] NULL,
[SeniorLienBalance] [money] NULL,
[OriginalCommitmentAmount] [money] NULL,
[CurrentCommitmentAmount] [money] NULL,
[OriginalCombinedLTV] [float] NULL,
[CurrentCombinedLTV] [float] NULL,
[OriginalPropertyValue] [money] NULL,
[CurrentPropertyValue] [money] NULL,
[AppraisalDate] [date] NULL,
[AppraisalType] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
[PMI] [nchar](1) NULL,
[LoanPurpose] [nchar](1) NULL,
[OccupancyType] [nchar](1) NULL,
[DocumentationType] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
[OriginalFICO] [smallint] NULL,
[CurrentFICO] [smallint] NULL,
[LastFICOUpdatedDate] [date] NULL,
[DebtToIncomeRatio] [float] NULL,
[InterestOnlyPeriod] [smallint] NULL,
[Modication] [nchar](1) NULL,
[Foreclosure] [nchar](1) NULL,
[ArmProductType] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
[ArmMargin] [float] NULL,
[ArmIndexType] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
[FirstRateAdjustmentDate] [date] NULL,
[NextRateAdjustmentDate] [date] NULL,
[LifeFloor] [float] NULL,
[LifeCeiling] [float] NULL,
[InitialRateCap] [float] NULL,
[PeriodicRateCap] [float] NULL,
[InternalRiskRating] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
[CurrentDebtServiceRatio] [float] NULL,
[CurrentNetOperIncome] [float] NULL,
[OriginalDebtServiceRatio] [float] NULL,
[OriginalNetOperIncome] [float] NULL,
[CurrentOccupancy] [float] NULL,
[PropertyTotalSquareFootage] [int] NULL,
[UnitCount] [smallint] NULL,
[PrepaymentPenalty] [nchar](1) NULL,
[PrepaymentPenaltyType] [int] NULL,
[PrepaymentPenaltyTerm] [smallint] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_ReviewSamplingLoans] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ReviewSamplingLoans]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_ReviewSamplingLoans_ReviewCollateralTypes] FOREIGN KEY([LoanType])
REFERENCES [dbo].[ReviewSamplingLoans] ([Code])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ReviewSamplingLoans] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_ReviewSamplingLoans_ReviewCollateralTypes]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ReviewSamplingLoans]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_ReviewSamplingLoans_ReviewSamplingFiles] FOREIGN KEY([ReviewId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Reviews] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ReviewSamplingLoans] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_ReviewSamplingLoans_ReviewSamplingFiles]
GO
```

Regarding Size, excel file contains 20000 rows which are added to datatable upon validation and using sqlbulkcopy inserting into table.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yingqin/archive/2014/02/28/preliminary-findings-to-get-good-performance-of-sqlbulkcopy.aspx

Comment: Without any specific information it's hard to respond. *How* are you using SqlBulkCopy? What are you passing, a DataTable, DataReader? How big are the records? Fast or slow network? Are you using transactions? Does the target table have triggers? What is the recovery model of the database?

Comment: we are passing datatable to SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer, minimum record count is 20000. Network is relatively good and we are not using transactions.

Comment: Target table does not contain triggers.

Comment: OK, let's start with the basics 1) show us the full SQL definition of the table you are inserting into, 2) what is the throughput of your network, 3) how large (avg) is each record?

Comment: Oh and show us the code calling `SqlBulkCopy`.

Comment: network throughput is 10mbps, destination table contains 75 columns.

Comment: using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(dConn))
                    {
                        bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("SamplingFileId", "SamplingFileId");
                        

   bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 500;
                        //Assign Destination Table Name
                        bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "cvr_ReviewSamplingLoans";
                        bulkCopy.BatchSize = 5000;
                       
                        bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dtLoansToUpload);

}

Comment: above code is not complete, we have columnmappings for 75 columns..

Comment: Again, we need the full SQL definition of the table including any keys, indexes. Please edit your question and add that in. If you don't know how to get that, let us know and we can explain it. Also we need the average size *in bytes* of your records.

Comment: Hi, i have provided sql table definition and looking for answer.

Comment: See  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24200/whats-the-fastest-way-to-bulk-insert-a-lot-of-data-in-sql-server-c-client

Answer (score 0):

SqlBulkCopy can be performed faster when you enable the Tablelock on the options.

Have a look here [SqlBulkCopyOptions Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopyoptions(v=vs.110).aspx)

But keep in mind that once the operation has started, no one will be able to use the table until it is finished. Microsoft says that this tenchnique improves the speed when inserting large amounts of data.