# SQL Server - Updating data with effectiveFrom and EffectiveTo dates - Upsert optimisation

Tags: sql-server, temporal-tables

We have a requirement to create a table that maintains temporal validity (i.e. for a given key, in this case Md5 in the table below, there will be no overlapping periods). Users need the ability to set the `EffectiveFrom` and `EffectiveTo` dates therefore the temporal tables are not useful as they only appear to allow system generated dates.  The use case is that bulk data will be uploaded with the validity date range set and this needs to be applied to the existing data to ensure that there are no period overlaps.

Table definitions:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.IngestedData', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE IngestedData;

CREATE TABLE IngestedData
(   
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    Md5 VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,   
    EffectiveFrom DATE NOT NULL,    
    EffectiveTo DATE NOT NULL,
    UpdateUser VARCHAR(50),
    JsonData VARCHAR(MAX),
    CONSTRAINT CK_IngestedData_Start_End CHECK (EffectiveFrom < EffectiveTo),
    CONSTRAINT UK_IngestedData_Md5_Start_End UNIQUE(Md5, EffectiveFrom),
    PRIMARY KEY (Id)
);

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX AK_IngestedData_Md5 
   ON IngestedData (Md5); 
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX AK_IngestedData_EffectiveFrom   
   ON IngestedData (EffectiveFrom);
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX AK_IngestedData_EffectiveTo 
   ON IngestedData (EffectiveTo);
```

I have written an upsert procedure that works well for single row updates as follows:

Upsert procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_UpsertIngestedDataRow 
    @Md5 VARCHAR(20),
    @EffectiveFrom DateTime,
    @EffectiveTo DateTime,
    @UpdateUser VARCHAR(50),
    @JsonData VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    BEGIN TRY;
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;
        --Select the data that needs to be modified along with the action to be taken
        WITH NewRow(ID, Md5, EffectiveFrom, EffectiveTo, UpdateUser, JsonData, [Action]) AS
        (
            SELECT NULL, @Md5, @EffectiveFrom, @EffectiveTo, @UpdateUser, @JsonData, 'I'
        ),
        OverlappingRows(ID, Md5, EffectiveFrom, EffectiveTo, UpdateUser, JsonData) AS
        (
            SELECT 
                X.ID, X.Md5, X.EffectiveFrom, X.EffectiveTo, X.UpdateUser, X.JsonData 
            FROM 
                NewRow A 
            JOIN 
                IngestedData X ON (X.EffectiveFrom < A.EffectiveTo
                               AND X.EffectiveTo > A.EffectiveFrom)
                               AND A.Md5 = X.Md5
        ),
        NewStartRows(ID, Md5, EffectiveFrom, EffectiveTo, UpdateUser, JsonData, [Action]) AS
        (
            SELECT 
                s.ID, s.Md5, s.EffectiveFrom, 
                (SELECT DATEADD(DAY, -1, MIN(EffectiveFrom)) 
                 FROM NewRow), 
                s.UpdateUser, s.JsonData, 'I'
            FROM
                OverlappingRows s
            WHERE 
                EffectiveFrom < (SELECT MIN(EffectiveFrom) FROM NewRow)
        ),
        NewEndRows(ID, Md5, EffectiveFrom, EffectiveTo, UpdateUser, JsonData, [Action]) AS
        (
            SELECT 
                s.ID, s.Md5, 
                (SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, MIN(EffectiveTo)) 
                 FROM NewRow), 
                s.EffectiveTo, s.UpdateUser, s.JsonData, 'I'
            FROM  
                OverlappingRows s
            WHERE 
                EffectiveTo > (SELECT MAX(EffectiveTo) FROM NewRow)
        ),
        DeleteRows(ID, Md5, EffectiveFrom, EffectiveTo, UpdateUser, JsonData, [Action]) AS
        (
            SELECT 
                del.ID, del.Md5, del.EffectiveFrom, del.EffectiveTo, 
                del.UpdateUser, del.JsonData, 'D'
            FROM
                OverlappingRows del 
            INNER JOIN 
                NewRow n ON n.EffectiveFrom <= del.EffectiveFrom 
                         AND n.EffectiveTo >= del.EffectiveTo
        )
        SELECT *
        INTO #Temp
        FROM
            (SELECT * FROM NewRow
             UNION
             SELECT * FROM NewStartRows
             UNION
             SELECT * FROM NewEndRows
             UNION
             SELECT * FROM DeleteRows) AS Data;

        --Delete any rows that are being replaced
        DELETE FROM IngestedData WHERE ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM #Temp)

        --Insert the replacement
        INSERT INTO IngestedData(Md5, EffectiveFrom, EffectiveTo, UpdateUser, JsonData) 
        SELECT Md5, EffectiveFrom, EffectiveTo, UpdateUser, JsonData
        FROM #Temp
        WHERE [Action] = 'I'

        --Drop temp table
        IF  OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#Temp', 'U') IS NOT NULL
            DROP TABLE #Temp

    COMMIT;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK;
        THROW;
    END CATCH


END
GO
```

The individual call performance is good with a call taking around 7ms even when the table is populated with 10,000,000 records.  The issue is making large number of updates.  Executing the above stored procedure for 35,000 records via a cursor takes around 5 minutes.

I tried rewriting the procedure to take a table variable which would allow the DML to use set operations but got lost in the logic. Can anyone help to turn the above logic in to a set based update that follows this pattern:

New stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_BulkUpsertIngestedData 
    @UpdateUser VARCHAR(15), 
    @NewRows DataIngestionRecord READONLY
AS
BEGIN
```

**Type definition**

```
CREATE TYPE DataIngestionRecord AS TABLE
            (
                Md5 VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,   
                EffectiveFrom DATE NOT NULL,    
                EffectiveTo DATE NOT NULL,
                JsonData VARCHAR(MAX)
            )
```

Comment: Have you considered dropping/disabling your indexes and recreating/enabling them after the import? This _should_ improve performance.

Comment: this might be helpful too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2899468/57475

Comment: and this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/prerequisites-for-minimal-logging-in-bulk-import

Comment: Thanks @Tanner but I may have mislead you.  I am not using bulk import as these have no way to apply the necessary temporal period changes to existing data.  I am looking for a way to apply the same logic that is in the stored procedure for a single update to a set of updates passed in a table variable.  Set operations generally perform faster in SQL that repeatedly running row based operations.  I will modify my question to make that clearer

Comment: @Tanner,  having read through your first comment in more detail I gave it a quick try on a small set of data and it greatly improved the performance.  I am going to do a test on a larger set of data but it looks like a way to significantly increase the performance!

Comment: also, the chained cte will likely reduce performance with larger datasets. try reforming the cte's as #temp tables instead, i've found that helps performance wise in the past. check out the examples in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26205087/57475 to see if it would be applicable in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having tried both disabling then rebuilding the indexes and removing the CTE in the procedure I found that performance was really not improved at all when using row by row updates.

I took another tack and decided that I could limit the upsert use case by specifying that in any given update each unique Md5 could only have one new temporal range applied.  This simplified the logic required to convert the stored procedure in to a set based operation (and fits with our requirements).

I did take @Tanner's advice and remove the chained CTE from the stored procedure. The final stored procedure ended up as:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_UpsertIngestedDataSet 
    @NewRows DataIngestionRecord READONLY,
    @UpdateUser VARCHAR(15)
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    --Ensure that there are not multiple temporal regions in the update data for a given key
    SELECT Md5
    INTO #Duplicates
    FROM @NewRows
    GROUP BY Md5
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;

    IF(@@ROWCOUNT > 0) BEGIN
        DECLARE @Err VARCHAR(MAX)
        SELECT @Err = COALESCE(@Err + CHAR(13), '') + Md5
        FROM #Duplicates
        ORDER BY Md5;

        SET @Err = 'The following Md5 values have multiple temporal ranges in the uploaded data which is not supported: ' + char(13) + @Err;

        THROW 50002, @Err, 1;
    END

    --Determine all overlapping rows from the existing data set
    SELECT id.ID, id.Md5, id.EffectiveFrom, id.EffectiveTo, id.UpdateUser, id.JsonData
    INTO #OverlappingRecords
    FROM IngestedData id JOIN @NewRows nr ON 
        id.Md5 = nr.Md5 AND
        (id.EffectiveFrom < nr.EffectiveTo 
        AND id.EffectiveTo > nr.EffectiveFrom)

    --Calculate truncation of left overlapping rows
    SELECT ol.Id,ol.Md5, ol.EffectiveFrom, DATEADD(DAY,-1, nr.EffectiveFrom) AS EffectiveTo, 'U' AS Action
    INTO #Changes
    FROM #OverlappingRecords ol JOIN @NewRows nr ON 
        ol.Md5 = nr.Md5 
        AND ol.EffectiveFrom < nr.EffectiveFrom

    --Calculate truncation of right overlapping rows
    INSERT INTO #Changes
    SELECT ol.ID, ol.Md5, DATEADD(DAY,1,nr.EffectiveTo), ol.EffectiveTo, 'U'
    FROM #OverlappingRecords ol JOIN @NewRows nr ON
        ol.Md5 = nr.Md5 
        AND ol.EffectiveTo > nr.EffectiveTo
        AND ol.EffectiveFrom > nr.EffectiveFrom;

    --If any area overlaps both the left and right of a new region we need a new insert for the right overlap
    SELECT ol.ID, ol.Md5, DATEADD(DAY,1,nr.EffectiveTo) AS EffectiveFrom, ol.EffectiveTo, 'I' AS [Action]
    INTO #InsertRecords
    FROM #OverlappingRecords ol JOIN @NewRows nr ON
        ol.Md5 = nr.Md5 
        AND ol.EffectiveTo > nr.EffectiveTo
        AND ol.EffectiveFrom < nr.EffectiveFrom;

    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    --Delete all overwritten regions (i.e. existing temporal ranges that are completely replaced by a new range)
    DELETE FROM IngestedData 
    WHERE ID IN (SELECT ol.ID
                 FROM #OverlappingRecords ol JOIN @NewRows nr ON 
                    ol.Md5 = nr.Md5 
                    AND nr.EffectiveFrom <= ol.EffectiveFrom 
                    AND nr.EffectiveTo >= ol.EffectiveTo);

    --Insert New Data (both from uploaded data and from existing region splits)
    INSERT INTO IngestedData (Md5, EffectiveFrom, EffectiveTo, UpdateUser, JsonData)
    SELECT Md5, EffectiveFrom, EffectiveTo, 'user2', JsonData
    FROM @NewRows
    UNION
    SELECT id.Md5,ir.EffectiveFrom, ir.EffectiveTo,id.UpdateUser,id.JsonData
    FROM IngestedData id JOIN #InsertRecords ir
    ON id.ID = ir.ID AND ir.[Action] = 'I';

    --Update truncated rows
    Update id
    SET EffectiveFrom = u.EffectiveFrom, EffectiveTo = u.EffectiveTo
    FROM IngestedData id JOIN #Changes u ON id.ID = u.ID AND u.[Action] = 'U';

    COMMIT;

END
GO
```

Translating this code to set based logic made the difference and this version now completes 20,000 updates against 1,000,000 rows of data in a trifling 7370ms.